# Python rouding float with decimal module working, but not when using values in list afterwards

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, rounding, ironpython

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but I was not able to find a solution in any of them.
I rounding a float to 2 decimal digits and am using the decimal module for this purpose - as found in many other threads so far.
This is working pretty fine.

```
from __future__ import print_function #Working in IronPython2
from decimal import *

def ToDecimal(value, digits):

    getcontext().prec = digits
    value = round(value, ndigits=digits)
    return float(Decimal(str(value)))

a = 94.0478601564
b = 117.881296226

d = ToDecimal(a, 2)
e = ToDecimal(b, 2)

print (d)
print (e)

lst = [d, e]
print (lst)
```

This leads to the following output:

```
94.05
117.88
[94.049999999999997, 117.88]
```

So the decimal module does it job perfectly fine, but when I create a list with those values they just result in the same floating point problem I tried to avoid.

Is my understanding of how to use the decimal module fundamentally wrong or does it come from converting it to a float again?

Thanks in advance,
T.

Comment: Could be a IronPython2 issue.  I get the desired result on CPython 2.7 and 3.8.

Comment: @DarrylG Indeed itt is. I could have tried that myself, but I think I was too focused on IronPython...
This is a bit of an unfortunate now...
So my best shot will be to convert that to strings and trying to reconvert them to floats when needed, right? But I acutally fear that this will lead me back to a floating point problem again.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually remove the decimal function, you will get the desired output. I ran a sample (took out getcontext() since it wasn't defined in your snippet) and removed your decimal function. Thus, the code comes back

```
def ToDecimal(value, digits):
    value = round(value, ndigits=digits)
    return float(str(value))

a = 94.0478601564
b = 117.881296226

d = ToDecimal(a, 2)
e = ToDecimal(b, 2)

print (d)
print (e)

lst = [d, e]
print (lst)
```

Upon running this, You will get the output...
94.05...
117.88...
[94.05, 117.88]
[screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERRZ7.png)

Comment: @LoganBurleson--what version of Python are you running?  As my comment above the original code works in CPython which is what you seem to be running, but apparently doesn't work in IronPython. Perhaps you could test your code in IronPython.  Also, `getcontext` is defined in the [Decimal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) which OP is importing.

Comment: @DarrylG yes, I was using CPython. I just tried it in iron, and I see it is getting the same result that he was getting... I don't use iron very much, so I can try and get back asap. I guess I overlooked the #

Comment: @LoganBurleson
I basically agree, though I have been experiencing cases in which round also returned a quirky number due to the floating point problem. I am not able to reproduce an example like that now, but I will try to get a screenshot the next time this is happening.

The thing in my case is that I need to use IronPython as I am using Rhinoceros3D and it is working with IronPython.

Comment: @LoganBurleson, that code just returned the following output to me:
`94.05
117.88
[94.049999999999997, 117.88]`